# Getting error on video with Ruby on Rails 4 App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, video, ffmpeg

So this is the error I get right after I try and upload my video

[image]

This is my post show

```
<%= video_tag @post.video.url(:medium), controls: true, style: "max-width: 100%;" %>

<p>
  <strong>Description:</strong>
<%= @post.description %>
</p>
  <% if @post.user == current_user %>
  <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(@post) %> 
<% end %>|
<%= link_to 'Back', posts_path %>
```

This is my post model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user

 has_attached_file :video, styles: {
    :medium => {
      :geometry => "640x480",
      :format => 'mp4'
    },
    :thumb => { :geometry => "160x120", :format => 'jpeg', :time => 10}
}, :processors => [:transcoder]
validates_attachment_content_type :video, content_type: /\Avideo\/.*\Z/
end
```

I am curious if anyone has run into this before and I am wondering if I can get any help on how to fix this. I am using paperclip av-transcoder gem, ffmpeg and paperclip gem. I can add any more information if needed

Here is my post controller if this helps

```
def index
@posts = Post.all
end

def show
end

def new
@post = current_user.posts.build
end

def edit
end

def create
@post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
if @post.save
  redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.'
else
  render :new
end
end

def update
if @post.update(post_params)
  redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.'
else
  render :edit
end
end

def destroy
@post.destroy
redirect_to posts_url
end

private
def set_post
  @post = Post.find_by(id: params[:id])
end

def correct_user
  @post = current_user.posts.find_by(id: params[:id])
  redirect_to posts_path, notice: "Not authorized to edit this post" if @post.nil?
end

def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:description, :video)
end


 end
```

Comment: Can you open up your console and see if there are any errors?

Comment: @Uzbekjon I pulled up my browser console but didn't show anything. I don't know if you meant the rails console though

Comment: Nope, the browser console. Can you see add rendered HTML of that `video` tag as well? Let's see if there are any issues there...

Comment: @Uzbekjon Not sure what you mean. But is this what you're looking for  <video controls="controls" style="max-width: 100%;" src="/system/posts/videos/000/000/007/medium/20140710_175743_001.mp4?1461961478"></video>

Comment: Can you access your video file from the browser `/system/posts/videos/000/000/007/medium/20140710_175743_001.mp4?1461961478`?

Comment: Ya so I clicked it and then I get an error down in my console saying an error occurred while trying to load the resource

Comment: There you go... So the problem is probably in the URL of the file. Now you know where to look.

Comment: But the same thing happens with every file I try. So its not just that one URL

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your file is not converted properly. Please observe the logs after video is created to check if the conversion is done.

Also it might be better to move conversion into backgroud, it can take a long time to do: https://github.com/jrgifford/delayed_paperclip/